# Perfect matching in 5 dimensional hypercube

Tags: graph-theory

I was unable to understand what does $C_{4} \times C_{4} \times P_{n}$ mean in the [link](http://oeis.org/A028467) ? Also, I was curious to know if any recurrence relation or formula is there to derive at the given sequence?

Comment: You could try contacting the [author](http://www.theophys.kth.se/~phl/) of [the paper in the link](http://www.theophys.kth.se/~phl/Text/1factors2.pdf). The terms $C_m$ and $P_n$ in the paper without explanation.

Comment: $C_m$ is cyclic graph of $m$ vertices, $P_n$ is path graph of $n$ vertices. A hypercube of $n$ dimension is a product of $n$ copy of $P_2$. Please note that $C_4$ is isomorphic to $P_2 \times P_2$. So $C_4 \times C_4 \times P_m$ is isomorphic to $P_2 \times P_2 \times P_2 \times P_2 \times P_m$, a graph sort of like a hypercuboid but not a hypercube.

Answer (score 0):

A Cartesian Product on a graph is defined as follows: $G \square H$, with $V(G \square H) = V(G) \times V(H)$. Now for any vertex pair $(a, b), (c, d)$, the edge $(a, b)(c, d) \in E(G \square H)$ if $a = c$ and $bd \in E(H)$ or $b = d$ and $ac \in E(G)$.

Note that a perfect matching in the hypercube can be constructed as follows: match $v_{i}, v_{j} \in V(Q_{n})$ if $v_{i}$ and $v_{j}$ differ in exactly the first position. Observe that this is exactly the Cartesian product adjacency relation. We iterate on this, as $Q_{n}$ is the Cartesian product of $n$ instances of $K_{2}$.

Comment: I was not able to get it completely. In this [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Matching.html) , I found formula for calculating number of perfect matching in Cn and Pn graphs, but how do I compute formula for C4 X C4 X Pn which is mentioned in the question link, which is actually the cartesian product of 3 different graphs.

Comment: If possible, please explain your thought process/ method a bit.